# Which amplifier module to use for strain gauge/thermocouple voltage measurements through multimeter?

Tags: arduino, operational-amplifier, amplifier, strain-gage

I wish to measure the voltage difference across the ends of my load cell and [thermocouple](https://www.pyromation.com/Downloads/Data/emfk_c.pdf) using a multimeter, but my multimeter cannot accurately read such small voltages. The range of voltages to be measured is from ~0.1mV to 50mV and they are DC.

1. What amplifier can I use to amplify this voltage?
2. Is there a module for the Arduino that can accomplish the task?
3. Can I use an opamp with resistors to amplify the signal precisely using appropriate resistor values, or would that amplification be not very precise?

Please share links to the exact products that are fit for the job.

Note: Accuracy is critical for my task as the data is for research purposes. Also, the solution should not be too expensive (within 8-10 dollars.)

**EDIT1:** I wish to read the voltages from a DAQ for fast sampling. From what I understand and have observed using either the HX711 or the MAX6675 is that they are slow and reduce the frequency with which data can be taken.
What is the solution to this?

Comment: You seem to have two questions of application areas: (1) Load cell,, (2) Thermocouple. Both have very  low voltage outputs. For load cell a popular approach is using low frequency < 100Hz, mains freq filtering), low noise, high resolution (24 bit) application specific IC eg. HX711.

Comment: @tlfong01 I already have the HX711. But I want to put the voltage across the ends of the load cell and thermocouple as input to a DAQ. How can I use HX711 with that?

Comment: Are you using a bridge?

Comment: @Chu yes, I am using a load cell which has a 4 strain gauge bridge built into it.

Comment: @Atharva: It is still not clear if how your two applications: (1) load cell and (2) thermcouple, are related.

Comment: @tlfong01 related in what sense? I am using these in the same setup for different purposes and I wish to use the voltage differences, feed them to a DAQ and then postprocess to get values for temperature or weight

Comment: @Atharva:: You might like to skim my old post on how to use HX711 for load cell. My project has nothing to do with termocouple or temperature sensor. ***Reading old weight scale (Loadcell with HX711)***
https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=227137&hilit=hx711+tlfong01

Comment: @tlfong01 Thanks! Actually I have asked a question on HX711 [here](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/90184/prevent-resetting-of-null-weight-when-using-hx711-with-a-load-cell). If possible, please have a look.

Comment: @tlfong01 This is totally unrelated to the question, but, I was buying servos and I noticed [this](https://robu.in/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/TowerPro-MG995-Metal-Gear-Servo-Motor-ROBU.IN_.jpg). Seems to me its you. I was quite shocked to see tlfong01. Good work mate!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although they both use 'small voltages', load cells and thermocouples are very different beasts, needing very different optimisations for accuracy.

A thermocouple has an absolute output, and requires knowledge of the temperature of the metals it is connected to in order to get a true temperature reading. Assessing your state of knowledge from the question, I would say that the only thing you can do is to buy a 'thermocouple amplifier', which has built-in cold junction compensation and a defined mV/C output voltage, and follow its application notes carefully. An alternative is a 'thermocouple ADC' which has a direct digital output, as well as the built in cold junction. AD8495 and MAX31855 are examples of the former and latter respectively.

A strain gauge has a ratiometric output , so you either need an accurately stabilised supply voltage, or to measure the output using the supply as the reference to the ADC. Gain accuracy and even DC offset are relatively unimportant, as when using a strain gauge, you will (almost certainly) have calibrated for gain, and be doing a zero offset calibration frequently. Gain stability is rarely a problem in the amplifier, however good temperature stability of offset voltage will reduce the number of zero offset cals you have to do. Use a differential amplifier, either an op-amp plus resistors, or an integrated instrumentation amplifier, with a suitable gain. There is no point in recommending one of these, almost any will do, and to some extent you get the stability performance that you pay for.

Comment: Will using the MAX31855 reduce the sampling frequency? I am currently using the MAX6675 for the thermocouple and the readings take a significant amount of time. I need high sampling rates. What can be done? I have asked the question in detail [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/627349/sampling-bottleneck-due-to-sensor-conversion-time-max6675-max31855).

Comment: @Atharva Looks like the 6675 reads at 5 Hz to 12 bits, and the 31855 reads at 10 Hz to 14 bits. Note I've not studied the noise performance of the two data sheets, merely quoted the headline 'bits'. You'll have to read them carefully to see whether the 31855 is actually quieter, as well as being faster.

Answer (score 2):

What you basically want for this kind of application is an instrumentation amplifier. You can look up the architecture of an instrumentation amplifier and how it works.

You could build your own instrumentation amplifier from several discrete op-amps - this would be a good example project to learn about instrumentation amplifiers, in a real-world application example where you're processing a very small voltage from a sensor.

This would typically require that you provide the cold-junction compensation for the thermocouple yourself, whereas most modern thermocouple amplifier ASICs include it built into the chip.

There are instrumentation amplifier ICs such as the AD8495 specifically designed for thermocouple amplification, with built-in cold junction compensation, with an amplified analog voltage output. This would likely give you more accurate results than building the instrumentation amplifier yourself.

It is also increasingly common today to encounter thermocouple amplifier ASICs like the MAX31855, where the analog amplification and cold-junction compensation is combined with A-D conversion on the single chip, providing a digital interface such as SPI for readout of the thermocouple temperature.