# Sampling bottleneck due to sensor conversion time? MAX6675/MAX31855

Tags: arduino, sampling, thermocouple

The datasheets for the [MAX6675](https://robu.in/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/MAX6675-Datasheet.pdf) and [MAX31855](https://robu.in/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/datasheet.pdf) say that their "temperature conversion times" are 220 ms and 100 ms respectively. 
I am using an arduino to get the data from a K-type thermocouple through these modules. Does the "temperature conversion time" mean the time for which the arduino loop will stop for these modules to send the data?

My work requires high sampling rates. If these modules are going to take this much time on each loop iteration in the arduino code, then they will prove to the bottlenecks of data sampling, limiting it to ~5/10 Hz respectively.

Comment: The sensor doesn't know about your Arduino loop. Whether it stops for the data conversion time is *your* decision. The sensor only knows about the voltage and current of each pin on the sensor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the datasheets:

[image]

MAX6675: The micro reads the SPI data which takes a few µs. Then CS goes high, the chip begins a new conversion, while the micro does something else and waits 220ms before repeating the cycle with a new SPI read.

[image]

MAX31855: It does conversions constantly, the micro can do a SPI read at any time to get the latest value.

In both cases your code only needs to pause during the SPI transfer (or not if you're using interrupts). The micro can do something else while waiting for the 100ms or 220ms to pass.

**Edit:**

Either setup a timer to call a routine every 220ms to do the SPI read...

Or something like that:

```
{
    static unsigned last_millis;
    unsigned m = millis();
    if( (m-last_millis) > 220 ) { do the SPI read }
    last_millis = m;
}
```

Comment: What I am understanding is that I should not be reading data until the specified 220ms have passed, otherwise, the [temperature will never be updated](https://youtu.be/qub3yzqEwek?t=810). So, I can have a time_counter variable in my code using which the temperature is read only if its more than 220ms and after reading sets it back to 0. This way the arduino loop runs fast, and the temperature values are updated as well, but they are updated at 220ms. Is this much correct?

Comment: Yes. I've put some example code in the answer.

Answer (score 2):

> *Does the "temperature conversion time" mean the time for which the
> arduino loop will stop for these modules to send the data?*

Extracting the data (once the device has digitalized it) is the only overhead for the MCU: -

- For the MAX6675, you can extract the digital data at rates up to 4.3 Mbps. So, if your MCU can run its SPI bus at 4.3 Mbps, the 16 bits of data can be acquired in a little over 3.72 μs.
- For the MAX31855, you can extract the digital data at rates up to 5.0 Mbps. So, if your MCU can run its SPI bus at 5.0 Mbps, the 32 bits of data can be acquired in a little over 6.40 μs.

Comment: Please have a look at this [video](https://youtu.be/qub3yzqEwek?t=810). (I have timestamped the link at 13:30) The guy explains that it cannot go below the conversion time. If the delay in the arduino loop is smaller than the conversion time, the value that the module outputs does not change.

Comment: I think I have got my answer from what @bobflux wrote. The video also seems to make sense with that. My doubt was aimed at something different then what you focussed on.

Answer (score 2):

The conversion times are appropriate for a subset of typical thermal measurement and control applications. Slow conversion offers some advantages in noise reduction and ease of manufacturing a chip that satisfies a sufficient number of customers. The conversion does not block the controlling MCU program, but you are limited to eg. 10 conversions per second for the Maxim chip.

Incidentally, 10 conversions per second is sufficient for the vast majority of industrial temperature control applications, and even 3/second is pretty good.

If you need higher conversion rates, you can always create your own amplifier circuit, cold-junction compensation sensor and use them with your own choice of ADC.

Comment: Indeed, I did this recently [custom rolled], with a x100 preamp, AMC1035 ADC, and AVR64DA64. The hard part is decimation; I used several timer/counters in this MCU, via the event system, to obtain bit-exact 16-bit samples at ~180Sps. This may be more difficult to implement on other platforms. I do see there's an Arduino DxCore available, so this particular solution could be reproduced in the Arduino environment if one really wanted to. (I needed the SD ADC for isolation, transmitting a serial bitstream; any regular 16b SAR or SD ADC will do otherwise.)